# What is the big O time complexity of this function and how can I solve for it?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
void function(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }
    function(n-1);
    function(n/2);
}
```

I think it's O(2^(n*logn)), but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: An optimizing compiler could reduce it to O(1) since the function has no side effects and returns no values. In other words, calling `void do_nothing(int n) { }` would have the exact same affect on program state.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you could add a static counter to the start of the function, pass a number to your function, read your counter, and compare that result to your formula using the same value.  It may not tell you if you're right, but will probably tell you if you're wrong.

Comment: The question is interesting. But tell us why you think it's *O(2^(n * logn))* and how you are thinking to get that result. You will be more likely to get help here if you show your thought process rather than just asking for the answer.